# DOMException: The play() request was interrupted

Tags: javascript

This error [(The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv2NU.png) happen after several fast key down/up.
How can I fix it?

```
//audio will start plying with key down
function keydown() {
    if (audio.classList.contains('holding') == false) {
        if (audio.src != '') {
            audio.classList.add('holding');
            if (audio.paused) {
                audio.play();          
            } else {
                audio.currentTime = 0;
            }
        } 
    }
}
//and audio will stop playing with key up
function keyup() {
    if (audio.src != '') {
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
    audio.classList.remove('holding');
}
```

Comment: Don't press the button so fast? This seems like a user problem, not a code problem, to me.

Comment: Does it matter to set audio base64 (30MB) as src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because of the delay that occurs while processing the audio file.

I solved this by adjusting the audio base64 size limit (for example 5MBs).